# Использование метода getFullYear()

Tags: javascript

Есть рабочий скрипт:

```
var ads = [
    {
        on: (new Date("December 1, 2015")).getTime(),
        off: (new Date("March 1, 2016 23:59:59")).getTime(),
```

Хочу его модифицировать, так чтобы не менять постоянно год.

Использовал функцию getFullYear() для 2015 и getFullYear() + 1  для 2016

```
var date = new Date();
var ads = [
    {
        on: (new Date("December 1", " + date.getFullYear())).getTime(),
        off: (new Date("March 1", " + date.getFullYear() + 1 23:59:59")).getTime(),
```

Не получается. Подскажите почему?

Comment: Вам даже редактор SO подсвечивает что у вас ошибки в расстановке кавычек и знаков конкатенации

Comment: Подскажите как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых – у вас лишняя кавычка, внимательнее

```
var date = new Date();
var ads = [
    {
        on: (new Date("December 1, " + date.getFullYear())).getTime(),
        off: (new Date("March 1, " + (date.getFullYear() + 1) + " 23:59:59")).getTime(),
```

Во-вторых – может все таки немного грамотнее писать стоит?

```
var date = new Date();
var ads = [
    {
        on: new Date(date.getFullYear(), 11, 1).getTime(),
        off: new Date(date.getFullYear() + 1, 2, 1, 23, 59, 59).getTime(),
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: @Serg888 обновил ответ

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, исправлю!